# Could anyone tell me what are these things in a Roomba robot and how to clean them, please?

Tags: roomba

I'm really in doubt whether it is proper to ask this question here, so I'm apologizing if it is not, I'll delete it.

I have a Roomba robot which has worked for me for more than three years, and now while it is working it is producing some strange sounds, so I've decided to clean it thoroughly.

But when I disassembled it down to this point:

[image: Roomba disassembled]

I got stuck with these sort of glass things (marked with the red rectangles at the picture). They are really filthy from the inside and I cannot figure out how to clean them.

Does anyone know how one can remove dust from the inside on these things? May be there are some Roomba creators here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have one, but I found this article:

http://www.robotreviews.com/chat/viewtopic.php?t=10631

There they say the "cliff sensors" collect a lot of dust and can be cleaned out with a blast of compressed air. From the article, these sensors detect the floor and prevent the Roomba from wandering off the top stair, or some similar mishap.

If these sensors are dirty, apparently it will keep stopping and beeping, thinking its route is blocked.

If you don't have a source of compressed air you can get "canned air" from specialist camera places, but it's expensive. Otherwise, just blowing hard (once per sensor, without getting any spit in there!) may do the trick but be careful not to damage anything...

Comment: thank you, I've cleaned them with a "blast of air" from a conventional vacuum cleaner